# Node.js on event when something is pushed to an array

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am new to Node.js and async. I have a Node.js script that pushes log messages to an array periodically. This is happening asynchronously.

I would like to know how can I listen on that array being updated?

Comment: possibly https://www.npmjs.org/package/observed

Answer (score 0):

found it: https://github.com/MatthewMueller/array

I didn't use npmjs.org/package/observed  as it requires unstable node version (11)

with array, i can easily, do .on('add') which listens for any addition